# Make div expand to occupy available height of parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code:

html:

```
<div class="tile">
    <h3>short</h3>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
    <h3>longLongLong longLongLong longLongLong</h3>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tile{
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #cecece;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.tile h3{
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: 61px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tile .content{
    height: 162px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

**fiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/v8Lhxk2v/

and I get this layout

[image]

but I need to get something like next image, without using js.

Can that be solved?

[image]

Comment: If you want to fill that space while the text has the same size, that's not possible. Is like saying that you want 2 + 3 to be equal to 6. You can align the texts if you want by making the title element to have the same height and then you can vertically align the text inside it, but the you will have some space above and under the title.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8Lhxk2v/2/) ?

Comment: @DavidDomain so dotdotdot will not add ...

Comment: I don't get what you want/need .. both images you show are exactly same to me ..

Comment: @caramba sure they are same. But first tile has a lot of free space, and .content has a lot of text, so it must be not 162px but higher, to add extra text into empty zone

Comment: I'm confused. What do you want to fill up the empty space with? Do you want the available space to be at the top instead of between the title and text?

Comment: @BillCriswell so must be: http://i.imgur.com/rXSCQR5.png

Comment: @caramba http://i.imgur.com/rXSCQR5.png

Comment: This is crazy... It is impossible...

Comment: @PraveenKumar all in this world is possible!
it's only question of the time

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I kinda agree... But not everything buddy. `:)`

Comment: @brabertaser1992 IE 6 does not have a valid box model. Do you agree? `:D`

Comment: @brabertaser1992 To have "dotdotdot" on multiline text you need a trick as it's not supported yet in pure css, so if you take DavidDomain's fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/v8Lhxk2v/2/, and add this trick to it, http://jsfiddle.net/LJ62x/, would that make it become how you want?

Comment: @LGSon i will check later

Comment: with adding a div of fixed height (262px = height of two fixed divs added together) you can make it work as so: http://jsfiddle.net/v8Lhxk2v/6/

Comment: Also, I don't understand all this dotdotdot stuff... you need to be more clear...

Comment: @PhilipBevan read about dotdotdot. I'm slicing content at the end with ...
if height is not fixed, dotdotdot will not work

Comment: [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl) seems to be a jQuery plugin for _advanced cross-browser ellipsis for multiple line_. Maybe no need of JS if this (very very clever) [multi-line ellipsis](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/) pure CSS solution already fills the need?

Answer (score 10):

Depending on browser support you can use `flex`.

The container would need:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
```

Here's a quick demo with example markup:

http://jsbin.com/xuwina/3/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 7):

Look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/v8Lhxk2v/4/

playing with `border-bottom` and `overflow:hidden` on the parent element.

```
.tile{
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #cecece;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-bottom: 22px solid #cecece;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tile h3{
    min-height: 25px;
    max-height: 61px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tile .content{
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: @brabertaser1992 where do you mention dotdotdot in the question?

Answer (score 5):

I would say try to position the content absolute to the bottom of the tile. 
In that case you can set the space where the content should end. Still you need to add an extra class to your content with the smaller title to be it larger than the other tile with the larger title.

Your HTML would be:

```
<div class="tile">
    <h3>short</h3>
    <!-- Added an extra class to the div -->
    <div class="content small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Within your CSS I changed this:

```
.tile .content{
    height: 162px;
    background-color:grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:30px;
}
.tile .small{height:216px;}
```

And then you get this result: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n0hu9frr/1/)

Let me know if this is a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 5):

Solving this problem is pretty simple with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

By creating a column flex container the flex items stack vertically. You can then apply `flex: 1` to the text box (`.content`) which makes it expand the full available height of the container.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"><!-- container to align .tile boxes in flexbox row; 
                         (this flexbox is optional) -->
    <div class="tile">
        <h3>short</h3>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
        <h3>longLongLong longLongLong longLongLong</h3>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- end #container -->
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    display: flex; /* establish flex container; 
                      aligns flex items (child elements) in a row by default; */        
}   

.tile {
    display: flex; /* establish (nested) flex container */
    flex-direction: column; /* override default row alignment */
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #cecece;
    /* float: left; */
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.tile h3 {
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: 61px;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tile .content {
    flex: 1; /* tells flex item to use all available vertical space in container */
    height: 162px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px 40px 10px; /* added bottom margin for spacing from container edge */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9hvy0vc/1/)

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More browser compatibility details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

---

#### Using Ellipsis (...)

If you want to apply ellipsis to a single line of text, CSS makes that somewhat easy with the [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property. It's still a bit tricky (due to [all the requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276)), but `text-overflow` makes it possible and reliable.

If, however, you want to use ellipsis on multi-line text – as would be the case here – then don't expect to have any fun. CSS doesn't provide a single property for doing this, and the workarounds are hit and miss. For details and methods see my answer here: [**Applying Ellipsis to Multiline Text**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276)

Comment: cool, this is something i would recommend. Thank you flexbox :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, pretty easy... make `<div class="move"></div>` and put your h3 into it like`:<div class="move"><h3>Short</h3></div>` now style that move div like so:

```
.move{height:100px;}
```

it workd, you are done :)

PS: make it with both of your h3s :)

well, there is a code:

css:

```
.tile{
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #cecece;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.tile h3{
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: 61px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tile .content{
    height: 162px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.move{height:100px;}
```

html:

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="move">
    <h3>short</h3>
        </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
    <div class="move">
    <h3>longLongLong longLongLong longLongLong</h3>
        </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would try another aproach. Using jquery you can calculate on window load the `height` of the highest `h3` and then, apply that height to all your `h3` inside your `tiles`.

I know you asked for a pure css solution, so it's ok if I don't get any credit, but I think this answer may be usefull for other users with the same problem so that's why I wrote it.

Something like this:

```
var maxHeight = -1;
$('.tile h3').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight)
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
});
$('.tile h3').each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
});
```

As you can see in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/v8Lhxk2v/5/)** (notice I removed the fixed `max-height`you added to the header and add a third `tile`with a "very long text" so you can check the exmaple better.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this** use extra `div` with wrap. `h3` & `div.content`  tag are wrapped by extra `div` and some css to be change as following:

```css
.tile > div {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 22px!important;
}
.tile {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #cecece;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.tile h3 {
  min-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.tile .content {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <div>
    <h3>short</h3>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
  <div>
    <h3>longLongLong longLongLong longLongLong</h3>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a fixed height:

```
.tile h3 {
    height: 65px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or accompanied by js (jQuery):

```
// Height handler
var headHeight = 0;

// Iterate throug all H3s an get highest
jQuery( 'h3' ).each( function() {

    // Get current height
    var currentHeight = jQuery( this ).height();

    // If higher as handler set as handler
    if( currentHeight > headHeight ) {
        headHeight = currentHeight;   
    }

} );

// Set the height of all H3s
jQuery( 'h3' ).css( 'height', headHeight );
```

This would be a pretty robust solution ...

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve by the `flexbox` Flexible Box Layout Module:

```
.tile{
   ...
   /* add the following line */
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
   ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/57yLgxsx/

This example works on Chrome you can check for the browser compability on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com)
 and then add the correct prefixes.

It depends on who you want to ensure compatibility ( last 2 vorsion of all browser, mobile or desktop or both ).

keep in mind that there are two versions of flexbox, the "old" and the "new". What I wrote above is the new.

This link can clarify some ideas
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/