# How to make ellipsis work on flex item with dynamic width (flex:1)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to implement `white-space: nowrap;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on a `flex:1;` div without setting the `max-width`. I want it to adjust to the width `flex:1` gives.

Here is a fiddle that explains what I want and what actually happens:
https://jsfiddle.net/dani3l/6y04bvu1/13/

I'd like to keep the solution css only if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329835/css-fit-content-div-to-remaining-space/33228704#33228704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to apply text-overflow: ellipsis, you have to give width or max-width otherwise it don't have any idea where it needs to stop.

Comment: So I guess I must use js to calculate the element width and set max-width on-the-fly.

Comment: yes. you can calculate that with js if your width is depend on other factor.

Comment: Try `width: 0; flex: 1`. I don't know if it works in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your flex:1 class:

```
.flex-1, .flex-1 > * {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here is a snippet to show this.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.flex-1, .flex-1 > * {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-1">
    This is very long text.
  </div>
</div>


<br>
<br>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-1">
    <div>
      Child divs work too
    </div>
    <br />
    <span>
      Child spans work too
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found [Larry Gordon's Codepen](http://codepen.io/psyrendust/pen/ZWPxmM/) that helped me with this.